# get a list of elements into the *.rar file in Linux

Tags: r, linux, unzip, unrar

I want to get a list of elements (files and folders) that are into the *.rar file.

I have a folder with a lot of *.rar files, each of *.rar have folders and files, I would to get a list of name of these folders.

I build this function:

```
lapply(tempzip,
                 function(x) unique(c(na.omit(str_extract(unlist
                                                          (unzip(zipfile = x, 
                                                                 list = TRUE)),
                                                          '(?<=/).*(?=_frames/)')))))
```

It works well for *.zip and *.rar files in Windows, but not for *.rar files in Linux.

How could I to do it works in Linux?

Thank's